# Can Vivaldi open tabs in the background?

Tags: browser-tabs, vivaldi

When using the Vivaldi browser (version 1.2), it is possible to right-click on a link in a web page and select *Open In New Tab*.  This, of course, is common to most browsers nowadays.

Other browsers have a user setting whereby the browser will remain on the source page, leaving the newly opened page to render in a background tab.  I find this useful if I want to open a couple of links on a page while continuing to read it.
Vivaldi always changes focus to the newly opened tab.

Vivaldi has no explicit setting to stay on the source page.  Neither can I find 
anything on [Vivaldi Tips](http://vivalditips.com/).

Is there a way, possibly a registry tweak, that will make Vivaldi stay on the page and make a newly opened tab render in the background?
It seems odd that a browser with so many customisation options can't do this.

Comment: Ctrl + left click is another option

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Rightclick on a link, and instead of choosing `Open in New Tab`, choose `Open in background tab`, which is 2 items down in that list.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I always open a new tab in background by clicking the mouse wheel. Tested on Vivaldi right now.

Comment: This is how I always use the web. And I have been using Vivaldi exclusively on my work computer for over a year now. I open so many tabs, and all with the middle mouse button, that a browser that could not support that would literally be unusable for me.

Comment: My middle mouse button has been set to double-click since before the scroll-wheel was invented. Too late for me to change my Pavlovian reflex now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Same as most browsers, Ctrl/click will open a new tab behind, Ctrl/shift/click will open in front. [Cmd on Mac]

Comment: Oh wow, ctrl+shift+click... I have wanted that so many times :O

Comment: @DavidMulder - I couldn't live without it ;) It does seem to be consistent across browsers too.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on any link, there's the option to "Open link in background tab".

Answer (score 1):

On Mac to open new link in the background, press: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd> (Windows <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>) while clicking on the link. The same shortcut works in Chrome, Firefox and other major web browsers.

Comment: Does it need the alt/opt?? Mine never has, since the dawn of time -  just cmd[ctrl] or cmd[ctrl]/shift. Ahhhh... adding alt/opt sets it to a new window, rather than new tab, just tested.